# PrimeNG multiselect select and deselect value

Tags: toggle, primeng, multi-select

How do we know in primeNG multiselect whether value/object is selected or deselected.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

```
    onChange    event.originalEvent: browser event
    event.value: Current selected values
    event.itemValue: Toggled item value
```

event.value always return the latest array of selected values
event.itemValue returns the selected/unselected value

I found in the documentation these three events and in debugging I didn't find any selection and deselection attribute.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
PG

Comment: You need to bind value in variable using [(ngModel)] attribute

Comment: with [(ngModel)] you will get all selected value's not the current one, current one comes only with (onChange) event of multiselect, however, it doesn't show the action (select or deselect) that's what I want.. Hope it is clear!!

Answer (score 2):

Although I am answering it after a long time the question has asked, but it will help others may be.

event.value: Current selected values array

event.itemValue: Toggled item value

To identify whether the checkbox selected or deselected, just check the event.itemValue is present in the event.value array.

if found in the array then selected otherwise take as deselected.

@Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var checked = false;
if (event.value.map((a) => a.id == event.itemValue.id).length == 1) {
    checked = true;
}
```