# primeNG multiselect on change not triggered on chips removal

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, multi-select

below is a sample of my code. A primeng multiselect is the source of a primeng dropdown:

HTML:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="elements" [(ngModel)]="selectedElements" optionLabel="name" display="chip"
  (onChange)="onElementChange($event)"></p-multiSelect
  
<p-dropdown [options]="availableElements" [(ngModel)]="selectedElement" optionLabel="elementID"
      placeholder="Select an Element"></p-dropdown>
```

ts:

```
onElementChange(event) {
  this.availableElements = [];
  this.availableElements = event.value;
}
```

Selecting elements from the multiselect dropdown is full working, but when I remove an element from the multiselect chips, then the onChange event is not triggered:

[image]

How can I trigger the onChange? Is it a not supported event?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look here ? [primeng-multiselect-select-and-deselect-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957352/primeng-multiselect-select-and-deselect-value)

Comment: @LuayAL-Assadi yes but the problem is that the event is not triggeret at all when the x is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's considered a bug of the component because the internal state has been updated when you remove it... so temporarily you need to update the state by using **onClick** event and a template variable to get the component value.

```html
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCities2" 
        defaultLabel="Select a City" optionLabel="name"
        display="chip" 
        (onClick)="selectedCities2 = elm.value" 
        #elm>
</p-multiSelect>


{{selectedCities2| json}}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-update-model-fix?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bug fixed since 12.2.2 primeng version